# Any specific Id obj can be duplicated inside the array, but apart from this, if duplicate Id objects come,then they should be removed from that array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

I want that, objects can be duplicate in the array,  if their id is 5(id===5). apart from that, any duplicate Id's objects coming, it should be remove from array.

for example

INPUT

```
const arrData = [{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"david"},{id:5,name:"rohn"},{id:4,name:"Alex"},{id:1,name:"roy"},{id:5,name:"malan"},{id:3,name:"jonny"},{id:2,name:"rod"}]
```

OUTPUT

```
[{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"david"},{id:5,name:"rohn"},{id:4,name:"Alex"},{id:5,name:"malan"},{id:3,name:"jonny"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to keep track of ids seen previously, then filter out duplicates unless their id is 5.

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"david"},{id:5,name:"rohn"},{id:4,name:"Alex"},{id:1,name:"roy"},{id:5,name:"malan"},{id:3,name:"jonny"},{id:2,name:"rod"}]

const s = {}
console.log(arr.filter(({id}, t) => (t=!s[id], s[id]=1, t || id===5)))
```

or with an array of ids seen previously:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"david"},{id:5,name:"rohn"},{id:4,name:"Alex"},{id:1,name:"roy"},{id:5,name:"malan"},{id:3,name:"jonny"},{id:2,name:"rod"}]

const s = []
console.log(arr.filter(({id}, t) => (t=!s.includes(id), s.push(id), t || id===5)))
```

Comment: @ Andrew Parks  Thanks for this solution. I just want ask you that, why you put that s[id]=1 here

Comment: @vjtechno `s` is an object that contains key/value pairs. All I needed was to set the key to something, so that the `s[id]` check would see that it is set. The code would work just as well if you changed it to `s[id]='hamburger'`

Comment: @vjtechno I wrote a second version into the answer, that uses an array instead. It's less concise, but makes it easier to see what is going on

Comment: A JS Set would be better/faster than using an array.

Comment: @RyanWheale I agree, the array snippet was only to help explain what is going on. The first snippet is fastest, and is 2.5x faster than a Set https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/5364/0/set-vs-object-vs-map

Comment: @Andrew Parks Thanks for explain me. If I want that, objects can be duplicate in the array, if their name is john(name==='john'). apart from that, any duplicate name's key objects coming, it should be remove from array. How we can achieve with first solution which is you mentioned 
Thanks

Comment: @vjtechno just change `id` to `name` and change `id===5` to `name==='John'`. Remember, it will be case sensitive